# Azure form recogniser less accuracy and taking more time

Tags: azure, azure-devops, ocr, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I really need some suggestions regarding azure form recognizer.
I am working on app where user will upload image of ID cards, (format can be jpeg, jpg, pdf). and i have to extract information with mapping. for that i have used form recognizer. but the problem was the accuracy is less for bad images and it was collection some garbage sometimes, and the time to process is also 45 seconds for one image.

so i thought to use azure ocr for it, i used classifier code and then azure ocr. now i have to map the json file.

my output will be kind of like this:

```
public virtual int Id { get; set; }
```

my question is, am i in the wrong path? or the right one. if i am in the wrong path what should i follow?
also is there any AZURE classifier which i can use before form recognizer?
and is there any automatic json mapping service in azure?

Would you kindly give your suggestions what i should do to increase the accuracy and reduce the timing/?

should i move to OCR? or stick to form recognizer?
or should I build a custom model using python?

```
public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
public virtual string Sex { get; set; }
public virtual DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can you please share the images that took 45 seconds to process and output that has been extracted.

Comment: Form Recognizer expects a document type per file, if your have several different documents or forms in one file please split the file into pages or the single documents before sending it to Form Recognizer. You can use a logic app or flow connector for this or any other simple code to split the document to pages.